# git-lfs checkout remote branch

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-lfs

I'm trying to checkout a branch from a remote that uses lfs to store files:

```
git remote add remoteRepo git@github.com:user/remoteRepo-lfs.git
git fetch remoteRepo
git checkout -b test remoteRepo/master
```

It is worth mentioning that the remote has been subject to the bozaro/git-lfs-migrate tool. The checkout process stops with an error and a

```
git lfs logs last
```

shows:

```
git-lfs/1.4.4 (GitHub; linux amd64; go 1.7.3; git cbf91a9)
git version 2.10.2

$ git-lfs smudge -- testText.log
Error downloading object: testText.log (dc56c0fc4d655b0895d83cd61b121f30cb74bda428655db4144e4a1c8b582b57)

Smudge error: Error buffering media file: Object not found on the server.: 
github.com/github/git-lfs/errors.newWrappedError
    /Users/ttaylorr/dev/go/src/github.com/github/git-lfs/errors/types.go:166
github.com/github/git-lfs/errors.NewSmudgeError
    /Users/ttaylorr/dev/go/src/github.com/github/git-lfs/errors/types.go:252
github.com/github/git-lfs/lfs.PointerSmudge
    /Users/ttaylorr/dev/go/src/github.com/github/git-lfs/lfs/pointer_smudge.go:69
github.com/github/git-lfs/lfs.(*Pointer).Smudge
    /Users/ttaylorr/dev/go/src/github.com/github/git-lfs/lfs/pointer.go:64
github.com/github/git-lfs/commands.smudgeCommand
    /Users/ttaylorr/dev/go/src/github.com/github/git-lfs/commands/command_smudge.go:66
github.com/github/git-lfs/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute
    /Users/ttaylorr/dev/go/src/github.com/github/git-lfs/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:477
github.com/github/git-lfs/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute
    /Users/ttaylorr/dev/go/src/github.com/github/git-lfs/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:551
github.com/github/git-lfs/commands.Run
    /Users/ttaylorr/dev/go/src/github.com/github/git-lfs/commands/run.go:65
main.main
    /Users/ttaylorr/dev/go/src/github.com/github/git-lfs/git-lfs.go:33
runtime.main
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.7.3/libexec/src/runtime/proc.go:183
runtime.goexit
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.7.3/libexec/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2086

ENV:
LocalWorkingDir=/home/person/Projects/proteus/proteus
LocalGitDir=/home/person/Projects/proteus/proteus/.git
LocalGitStorageDir=/home/person/Projects/proteus/proteus/.git
LocalMediaDir=/home/person/Projects/proteus/proteus/.git/lfs/objects
LocalReferenceDir=
TempDir=/home/person/Projects/proteus/proteus/.git/lfs/tmp
ConcurrentTransfers=3
TusTransfers=false
BasicTransfersOnly=false
BatchTransfer=true
SkipDownloadErrors=false
FetchRecentAlways=false
FetchRecentRefsDays=7
FetchRecentCommitsDays=0
FetchRecentRefsIncludeRemotes=true
PruneOffsetDays=3
PruneVerifyRemoteAlways=false
PruneRemoteName=origin
AccessDownload=none
AccessUpload=none
DownloadTransfers=basic
UploadTransfers=basic
GIT_DIR=.git
GIT_PREFIX=
```

A git-lfs env shows:

```
git-lfs/1.4.4 (GitHub; linux amd64; go 1.7.3; git cbf91a9)
git version 2.10.2

Endpoint=https://github.com/username/repo.git/info/lfs (auth=none)
  SSH=git@github.com:username/repo.git
Endpoint (remoterepo)=https://github.com/username/remoteRepo.git/info/lfs (auth=none)
  SSH=git@github.com:username/remoteRepo.git
LocalWorkingDir=/home/person/Projects/proteus/proteus
LocalGitDir=/home/person/Projects/proteus/proteus/.git
LocalGitStorageDir=/home/person/Projects/proteus/proteus/.git
LocalMediaDir=/home/person/Projects/proteus/proteus/.git/lfs/objects
LocalReferenceDir=
TempDir=/home/person/Projects/proteus/proteus/.git/lfs/tmp
ConcurrentTransfers=3
TusTransfers=false
BasicTransfersOnly=false
BatchTransfer=true
SkipDownloadErrors=false
FetchRecentAlways=false
FetchRecentRefsDays=7
FetchRecentCommitsDays=0
FetchRecentRefsIncludeRemotes=true
PruneOffsetDays=3
PruneVerifyRemoteAlways=false
PruneRemoteName=origin
AccessDownload=none
AccessUpload=none
DownloadTransfers=basic
UploadTransfers=basic
git config filter.lfs.smudge = "git-lfs smudge -- %f"
git config filter.lfs.clean = "git-lfs clean -- %f"
```

I have cloned remoteRepo-lfs successfully with

```
git clone git@github.com:user/remoteRepo-lfs.git
```

and have also been able to successfully checkout the branch by specifying in a .lfsconfig file:

```
[lfs]
  url = https://github.com/username/remoteRepo-lfs.git
[remote "remoteRepo"]
  lfsurl = https://github.com/username/remoteRepo-lfs.git/info/lfs
```

which seems to overwrite the endpoint url for origin. Is there a way to setup the local directory such that I can push/pull/checkout lfs files from origin and remotes based on their respective endpoint urls?

Comment: What is "test" in "git checkout -b test remoteRepo/master" command?

Comment: That would be the name of the local branch that tracks the remoteRepo/master branch.

Comment: Does it occur if you pull it?

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT I'm not sure what you mean by "pull it". My understanding is that upon adding a remote, I have to fetch the remote, and then I can checkout a branch that tracks a remote branch. Once the branch is checked out, then I can do a "git pull" periodically which is effectively a "git fetch" and "git merge" to update my local copy of the branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a workaround to this problem that I am encountering by modifying the lfs filter (in ~/.gitconfig). Namely:

```
[filter "lfs"]
  smudge = git-lfs smudge --skip %f
  required = true
  clean = git-lfs clean -- %f
```

git-lfs smudge converts the file pointers to the actual files. With this workaround, I have to perform a

```
git lfs fetch
```

followed by a

```
git lfs checkout
```

to retrieve/access the contents of the files. It is not clear to me why this workaround is necessary. Looking through the issues on the git-lfs, it seems like this is a general work in progress.

(e.g. https://github.com/github/git-lfs/issues/834).

Answer (score 0):

have you ever installed the git-lfs? If not, you can install [here](https://git-lfs.github.com/). It seems you have no **GIT_LFS_PATH** yet, my own environment can be referenced.

```
DownloadTransfers=basic
UploadTransfers=basic
GIT_LFS_PATH=C:\Program Files\Git LFS
git config filter.lfs.smudge = "git-lfs smudge -- %f"
git config filter.lfs.clean = "git-lfs clean -- %f"
```

And have you create a git-lfs repo on GitHub? You can try to use https://github.com/username/remoteRepo-lfs.git to check if it's really exist.

And I am also confused that your local directory like:

```
LocalWorkingDir=/home/person/Projects/proteus/proteus
LocalGitDir=/home/person/Projects/proteus/proteus/.git
LocalGitStorageDir=/home/person/Projects/proteus/proteus/.git
LocalMediaDir=/home/person/Projects/proteus/proteus/.git/lfs/objects
LocalReferenceDir=
TempDir=/home/person/Projects/proteus/proteus/.git/lfs/tmp
```

my local directory like this:

```
LocalWorkingDir=C:\Users\TFSTest\New folder\Git2
LocalGitDir=C:\Users\TFSTest\New folder\Git2\.git
LocalGitStorageDir=C:\Users\TFSTest\New folder\Git2\.git
LocalMediaDir=C:\Users\TFSTest\New folder\Git2\.git\lfs\objects
LocalReferenceDir=
TempDir=C:\Users\TFSTest\New folder\Git2\.git\lfs\tmp
```

Comment: git-lfs has definitely been installed because the command "git-lfs env" wouldn't work otherwise. I was under the impression that the default lfs server was the repo itself, which does exist. As for my local directory, I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Your directories seem to be indicative of a Windows system?

Comment: I'm having trouble finding complete documentation on the environment variables, but it appears the default value for `GIT_LFS_PATH` is `C:\Program Files\Git LFS` and you only need it explicitly set if you want a different value there.