# Can't check out branch with git-lfs, smudge error

Tags: git, git-lfs

I can't checkout a branch, git lfs returns an error. Other people in this project are able to check out this branch without problems, so it seems that the problem is on my end.
Here is the error I'm getting:

```
$ git checkout Camera_ObstacleDetection
Downloading iso-space/Assets/models/Puzzle_Room_1.fbx (155 KB)
Error downloading object: iso-space/Assets/models/Puzzle_Room_1.fbx 
(752f9dd): Smudge error: Error downloading iso- 
space/Assets/models/Puzzle_Room_1.fbx 
(752f9dd38daec0eda91f8317abcbf5d8c257abc8c9232f10af26bb93d9d0062c): 
[752f9dd38daec0eda91f8317abcbf5d8c257abc8c9232f10af26bb93d9d0062c] 
Object does not exist on the server: [404] Object does not exist on 
the server

Use `git lfs logs last` to view the log.
error: external filter 'git-lfs filter-process' failed
fatal: iso-space/Assets/models/Puzzle_Room_1.fbx: smudge filter lfs failed
```

I have tried editing `.gitconfig` as described [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40387376/git-lfs-checkout-remote-branch), but it didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: All I can tell you (I don't actually use Git-LFS) is that the way it works is that for large files, instead of storing the large file in the repository, Git-LFS stores a *URL* for the file. `git checkout` then takes that URL and tries to download the actual file. It's this download step that's failing. Git itself is working perfectly, and Git-LFS is doing its thing; it's the LFS download part that's the problem.

Comment: With that in mind, note the error: `404`, not found. This means the Large File Server (separate from Git) is claiming that the file *doesn't exist*. If it does exist and other users can get it, that means the server is *deliberately lying to you*, probably because it knows you're not to have access to the file, nor to even know if the file exists. So the obvious thing to do is to figure out why the LFServer doesn't trust you.

Answer (score 0):

After I set up git and github to use ssh and cloning the repository using ssh the problem disappeared. I tried to replicate it by removing ssh key and cloning using https and cloning to a new linux instalation, but unfortunately I wasn't able to, everything works just fine now. Perhaps it had something to do with github account but that's just a wild guess.

Edit: After working for about 2 hours I'm getting the same error again.